# Bumptech glide licensing

Tags: licensing, commercial, patents

I'm using **bumptech/glide** for loading images in my app.

After reading the License i saw that most of the library was licensed under the Apache License except for the AnimatedGifEncoder.

> License for third_party/gif_encoder/AnimatedGifEncoder.java and
>   third_party/gif_encoder/LZWEncoder.java:
>
> No copyright asserted on the source code of this class. May be used for any purpose, however, refer to the Unisys LZW patent for
>   restrictions on use of the associated LZWEncoder class. Please forward
>   any corrections to kweiner@fmsware.com.

I'm not using any **GIFS** so should i just fork Glide and remove the AnimatedGifEncoder from the library or should i just ignore this?

Comment: If the author is in the US, their work is in the public domain, as I read it. You can ignore and keep using it. Or is the question something more I don't quite get?

Comment: @Prof.Falkencontractbreached I'm using the glide library from github in my app, https://github.com/bumptech/glide/blob/master/LICENSE I list all licenses in the about section of my app (required by apache license) but then i can't find anything about the Unisys LZW patent

Comment: Patents are mostly orthogonal to licenses. The mention of the patent is just a "reader beware, there are *also other* issues you may want to consider, than the license and copyright status of this code". (In practice, this particular patent is expired: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch#Patents )